# Hypothesis testing and convergence of LRT statistic

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, likelihood-ratio, neyman-pearson-lemma

This may be a very simple question, but I am not sure about my logic.

I have a standard point hypothesis testing scenario, where I collect a sequence of $n$ independent observations $\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ and attempt to classify them as either generated from the distribution $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n;\theta=\theta_0)$ or $P(x_1,\ldots,x_n;\theta=\theta_1)$, where $\theta_0$ and $\theta_1$ are known.  Using the knowledge of the joint probability density function $f(x_1,\ldots,x_n;\theta)$, I can construct a [likelihood ratio test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Likelihood-ratio_test), which is optimal in the [Neyman-Pearson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neyman%E2%80%93Pearson_lemma) sense.  Let's denote the likelihood ratio test statistic by $\Lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$.

However, when either hypothesis $H_0$ or $H_1$ is true, the test statistic converges in probability to the same constant, i.e. $\Lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\xrightarrow{\mathcal{P}}\lambda$.  Formally, for any $\epsilon>0$, $\delta>0$, there exists $n_0$ such that for all $n\geq n_0$, the following equations hold:

$$\tag{1}P(|\Lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-\lambda|>\epsilon|\theta=\theta_0)<\delta$$
$$\tag{2}P(|\Lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)-\lambda|>\epsilon|\theta=\theta_1)<\delta$$

with $\lambda$ a known constant.

Does this mean that it's impossible to classify between $H_0$ and $H_1$, even as one obtains increasing number of observations?  I think it is and here is my logic.  Fix $\epsilon$ and $\delta$. Suppose our $n\geq n_0$ and suppose we would like to upper bound the probability of Type I error by $\delta$.  We thus select a threshold $t$ for the test such that

$$P(\Lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)>t|\theta=\theta_0)<\delta$$

By $(1)$ this implies that $t\geq\lambda+\epsilon$.  However, by $(2)$, this also implies that

$$P(\Lambda(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\leq t|\theta=\theta_1)\geq 1-\delta$$

resulting in the probability of Type II error being lower-bounded close to one.  I think means that no matter how you set your threshold, the best test is as good as deciding between the two hypothesis by flipping a coin (biased coin if there are unequal priors).

Is that correct?

Comment: Your equations (1) and (2) are surprising. What kind of weird model do you have? Or is it a situation where it is intuitively clear that the data do not provide any information about $\theta$ and you  want to prove it formally?

Comment: I am trying to formally prove that the data do not provide any information about $\theta$.